# Alternative cache policies in Caffeine

Tags: caching, policy, lru, caffeine

In my research, I take a trace and access Caffeine's cache only for some of the items in it. Hence, I collect my own hit / miss statistics, which is different from Caffeine's built-in statistics. This works great with Caffeine's default policy - Window-TinyLFU. However, I'd like to do the same with other cache policies.

Indeed, Caffeine's simulator suggests many cache policies, which can be chosen using the application.conf. file. However, AFAIK, the simulator behaves like a black box - running the whole trace, making its own statistics, etc. In other words, while Caffeine's builder allows defining some parameters (e.g. the cache's maximum-size), I didn't find any way to define there the cache policy.

Is there any way to do that? I'm intererested only in admission / eviction - (for now) I don't use a time-based expiration policy.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Caffeine's cache library and its simulator should be treated independently. The library is meant for application developers, so it is a black box that hides significant complexity and makes algorithmic choices. The simulator is for research and is a whitebox that can be directly modified.

Simply fork the repository and modify the simulator as you see fit. If possible we can merge your improvements upstream, but sometimes that requires more work since we have to maintain the code beyond an individual's research. By keeping a fork you won't be blocked or delayed in your work as we iterate it upstream. That way you shouldn't feel limited if we lack support for a requirement and can add those  missing pieces.

Since the simulator is used by only a handful of us, you can ask questions by opening a Github issue or may email me. Its structure is fairly straightforward:

- Simulator: orchestrates the process to run policies in parallel
- Registry: creates the configured policies
- TraceReader: a parser for a trace format
- PolicyActor: runs a batch of events against the policy
- Policy: a replacement algorithm that tracks its statistics
- Reporter: the pretty-printed result of the simulation.
- reference.conf: the externalized configuration

A simple example is [CaffeinePolicy](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/614fe6053e343481c15c55f1d696517d73baae0d/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/policy/product/CaffeinePolicy.java), which adapts from Caffeine's cache to the simulator's policy. A direct algorithm, like [SegmentedLruPolicy](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/614fe6053e343481c15c55f1d696517d73baae0d/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/policy/linked/SegmentedLruPolicy.java), includes an optional admission policy for use with its eviction policy.